# Display Jupyter notebook in GitHub

Tags: github, sas, jupyter-notebook

I have some Jupyter notebooks that I created using SAS University Edition. They run fine locally.

Question: Is it possible to have the notebook displayed with results on Githhub? I've seen it done for other languages so I'm not sure if I need to add something extra to my GitHub pages or to my notebook.

I'm pretty new at GitHub so it could just be user error.

If you need more information please let me know.

Here's a link to the SAS kernel on GitHub
 https://github.com/sassoftware/sas_kernel

Their sample notebooks don't show up either.

Comment: Convert the notebook first? http://blog.kdheepak.com/jupyter-notebook-revealjs-and-github-pages.html

Comment: SAS University edition is a locked down VM, so I'm not sure if it will be able to "see" github.

Comment: It doesn't need to see it, you can save and export the notebooks. It doesn't support automatic back ups but I don't mind manually upload the files. I think Github has actually fixed this issue but I haven't had a chance to test it yet.